# how can I get the hierarchy index of a TreeNode in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, datasource

I would like to retrieve from a `TreeView` the hierarchy of select node
for example:

1. Root1
      
   -item1
   --Item1.1
2. Root2
3. Root3

I would like to know how deep is the selected `TreeNode` 
 for example :  the index of root1 is 0, item1 is 1 and item1.1 is 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Level** to get the depth of TreeNode：

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Level;
```